# Changing the name of a file while in a filestream or byte array to send via WebAPI

Tags: c#, filestream

I would like to take the contents of a file and rename the file while in memory to send with a different file name using an API.

The Goals:

1. Not alter the original file (file on disk) in any way.
2. Not create additional files (like a copy of the file with a new name).  I'm trying to keep IO access as low as possible and do everything in memory.
3. Change the Name of a file object (in memory) to a different name.
4. Upload the file object to a WebAPI on another machine.
5. Have "FileA.txt" on source MachineA and have "FileB.txt" on destination MachineB.

I don't think it would matter but I have no plans to write the file back to the system (MachineA) with the new name, it will only be used to send the file object (in memory) to MachineB via a Web API.

I found a solution that uses reflection to accomplish this...

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"C:\myfile.txt", FileMode.Open);

var myField = fs.GetType()
    .GetField("_fileName", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)

myField.SetValue(fs, "my_new_filename.txt");
```

However, It's been a few years since that solution was given.  Is there a better way to do this in 2021?

Comment: Why do you care about the name?

Comment: The outfit providing the API for me to use allows it to be used to searchable after the fact.  The way the files are stored before sending them is in a multi-level directory hierarchy.  I basically just rename the file to all those directory names combined before sending.

Comment: I have no clue why they use the original file name at all...  I pass all this metadata along to the API telling them the filename etc.  Drives me nuts.

Comment: OK, so you need to use an API that relies on `FileStream.Name`, right? It would be good to mention this in the question. As this property is virtual, you might derive your own class from `FileStream` and override the property as you like.

Comment: @KlausGütter honestly I have no clue what they are doing on their side.  They might use FileStream, they might not.  I just know that when I send them a byte array they turn that into a file and tell me the file name is wrong.  I'm just using Filestream as a way for ME to change the contents of the file data (the file name specifically).

Comment: A byte array has definitely no file name. And the file name is *not* part of the file data. It must be something different going on here.

Comment: To the WebAPI this is what is being sent as the "content".  `var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent { { new ByteArrayContent(bytes), "mynewfilename", "mynewfilename.tif" } };`  I set the value of "newfilename" for the second and third params.  So if the external API is not getting it from the byte array I have no clue how they would know what the original file name was.

Comment: And how do you get `bytes` from the FileStream?

Comment: Currently, I don't.  That's what this question was going to end up helping me to achieve.   That would have more than likely been another SO question if I couldn't figure it out.  Right now I get bytes from the `System.IO.File` class.  `File.ReadAllBytes("myoldfilename.tif")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way I could come up with was using my old method from years ago.  The following shows how I used it.  I only do this to mask the original filename from the third-party WebAPI I'm sending it to.

```
// filePath: c:\test\my_secret_filename.txt

private byte[] GetBytesWithNewFileName(string filePath)
{
    byte[] file = null;

    using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    {
        // Change the name of the file in memory (does not affect the original file)
        var fileNameField = fs.GetType().GetField(
            "_fileName",
            BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic
        );
        // If I leave out the next line, the file name field will have the full filePath
        // string as its value in the resulting byte array.  This will replace that with
        // only the file name I wish to pass along "my_masked_filename.txt".
        fileNameField.SetValue(fs, "my_masked_filename.txt");

        // Get the filesize of the file and make sure it's compatible with 
        // the binaryreader object to be used
        int fileSize;
        try { fileSize = Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length); }
        catch(OverflowException)
        { throw new Exception("The file is to big to convert using a binary reader."); }

        // Get the file into a byte array
        using (var br = new BinaryReader(fs)) { file = br.ReadBytes(fileSize); }
    }

    return file;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One other way would be defining the filename when you save it on MachineB.
You could pass this filename as a payload through the Web API and use it as the file name.

```
//buffer as byte[] and fileName as string would come from the request
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
{
    fs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how you know WHICH web API the questioner is asking about.  In a web-browser I'd expect some response header: `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.jpg"`  Couldn't the asker just change that header?  It's really only a suggestion to the client anways... (client = MachineB I guess)

Comment: Yeah, I have no control over the 3rd party and their proprietary web API.  Nothing is going to change on MachineB's side.